# Visual Studio 2022 pairing to Mac fails while checking Mono installation

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, maui, pairing

**Good morning,**

I'm trying to expand my experience in IOS app development.

So I created a .NET MAUI solution, and by paring my Windows 10 machine with VS Pro 2022 17.4.2 and my MacBook macOS 12.6.1 21G217, Xcode Ver. 14.1 (14B47b) started.

This worked immediately after a short SSH key problem.

Now I had a project with a connected MacBook and I had to put my son to bed first. So I left everything in the connected state and took care of it.

After four hours I came back to my place of work and found that the connection was broken. No problem, I thought to myself and started the pairing again. And since then it doesn't work anymore. When the connection is established, the following message appears:

[image: Pairing Dialog]

So I've been wandering through google hoping to find a solution. Now if I had found something suitable, I probably wouldn't be standing here asking the professionals ;-)

**What have I tried so far?**

- Restart booth mashines
- In the solution I deleted the following solution directories: .vs, bin, obj <-- That didn't help.
- Delete directory on Windows `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\Xamarin\XMA`
- Delete directory on Mac `$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA`
- Delete directory on Mac `$HOME/Library/Logs/Xamarin-*` <-- Since the connection to the Mac can no longer be established, no Xamarin log is written to the Mac
- Start VS 2022 with "devenv.exe /log" <-- See following screenshot

**The result of the VS 2022 Xamarin Logs:**

[image: The .svclog screenshot]

I have the entry that the IDBAgent on the MacBook got something. Because the last few lines in `~/Library/Logs/Xamarin.Messaging-17.4.0.301/2022-12-07__20-46-20.IDB.log` were:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.ListenerProvider Information: 0 : Sending devices: iPhone SE (3rd generation) iOS 16.1, iPhone 14 iOS 16.1, iPhone 14 Plus iOS 16.1, iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.1, iPhone 14 Pro Max iOS 16.1, iPad Air (5th generation) iOS 16.1, iPad (10th generation) iOS 16.1, iPad mini(6th generation) iOS 16.1, iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) iOS 16.1, iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) iOS 16.1, Apple TV tvOS 16.1, Apple TV 4K (3rd generation) tvOS 16.1, Apple TV 4K (3rd generation) (at 1080p) tvOS 16.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple WatchSeries 6 (40mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (40mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (40mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (40mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (44mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (44mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch SE (44mm) (2nd generation) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Ultra (49mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Ultra (49mm) watchOS 9.1, Apple Watch Ultra (49mm) watchOS 9.1: 12/07/2022 19:53:57Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:53:57.2611150Z: 12/07/2022 19:53:57Z
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.Bindings.TcpChannel Warning: 0 : The underlying communication stream has completed sending bytes. The observable sequence will be completed and the channel will be disposed: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2045710Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.ClientPacketListener Warning: 0 : Client IDB1740301 - Packet Channel observable sequence has been completed: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2058850Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl Warning: 0 : Client - Packet observable sequence has been completed, hence closing the channel: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2061660Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner{Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.IDBAgent} Warning: 0 : The connection to the Broker has been lost, the Agent should terminate: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2338830Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.IDBAgent Information: 0 : Stopping: IDB: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2357010Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.IDBAgent Information: 0 : Killing existing MTouch processes before stopping the agent: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
    DateTime=2022-12-07T19:57:48.2361030Z: 12/07/2022 19:57:48Z
```

And now I don't know how to continue. Does anyone know how to check if the IDBAgent is running on the Mac or how to start it?

Or does anyone have any other ideas what happened while I was putting my child to bed?

I am grateful for every tip.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the pairing issue, you need to clear the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac. Please follow the steps below:

1. Run the following command in Terminal on the Mac:

```
open "$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin"
```

2. Control-click the `XMA` folder and select Move to Trash.
3. There is a cache on Windows as well that it may help to clear. Open a cmd prompt as Administrator on Windows:

```
del %localappdata%\Temp\Xamarin\XMA
```

After steps above, please try to pair to Mac again.For more details, you can refer to [Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting).

Comment: Yes i have done and read the link you attached. But still i get the same error. I have also delete the Xamarin logs on the Mac. And it wasn't recreat after a retry. So i think the SSH Connection is fine but the IDB Connection won't work.

Comment: @Marcus, as Gerald pointed out, it's a server-side issue and this has been fixed. The Connection is working.

Comment: yes i can confirm

Answer (score 1):

This was something that was caused on a server-side and we've resolved it as such. You should now be able to connect again!